# How Watson Discovery is different from Retrieve and Rank?

Tags: solr, watson-discovery

I'm trying to understand, from a technical perspective, how Watson Discovery works behind the curtains compared to Retrieve and Rank (which leverages Apache SOLR)?

Answer (score 3):

Watson Discovery is based on ElasticSearch and then exposes its own simplified query language for interaction. This allows for structured queries that enable aggregations and content analysis as well as free text queries.

Comparing the two services: Retrieve and Rank enables search with a machine learning rank model on private data while Discovery enables search and content analytics on a combination of private and public content with NLP enrichments.

Answer (score 2):

In both Watson Discovery & Retrieve and Rank, you need to provide your own data.

But, the difference lies in their way of processing the data, in R&R you need to train your own model .i.e. rank your answer based on all probable types of questions can be asked to watson. It uses another service, Document Conversion to retrieve the answer from your provided document (all by dividing a document into small sections)

Whereas, in Discovery, it acts as a service on the top of R&R, once documents are uploaded, it applies it own cognitive search capability to look for right answer (basically among your provided  documents) of your query.

For better understanding the process please go through their documentation:
[Retrieve and Rank](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/index.html)
and [Discovery](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, so how is Discovery better than Retrieve and Rank?

Comment: It depends. If you want to have full control over the question and answer .i.e. if you want to train watson according to you. I would suggest you to go for Retrieve and Rank

Comment: But for better usability perspective, it is always better to use Discovery service.

Answer (score -1):

If you are used to with Retrieve and Rank, Discovery can provide more or less similar results if you are using Relevancy training for Discovery.

As of now, Relevancy Training in Discovery is still in Beta.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/train.html

Technically, as @tmarkiewicz has suggested the Discovery feature of Watson analytics uses the 'Elastic Search', and has the capability of Natural Language Programming. It's a good feature to have when it comes to enriching the answers and providing high usability.